# Codeigniter form submit with file upload

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

im trying to write a code where i can submit a form enter the contents in a database, at the same time perform a file upload and have it stored in a folder inside my server

the folder location is called uploads which is located at the root of my site

here is my code

controller (site.php)

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Site extends CI_controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // Your own constructor code
    $this->load->model("site_model");
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
} 

public function cmain($type,$page)
{
    $data = $this->_initialize_data(); //this is just a bunch of variables that im calling in another function
    $data['type'] = $type;
    $data['page'] = $page;
    $this->load->vars($data);
    $this->load->view('site/cmain');
}


public function m1()
        {               

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if(isset($_POST['m1']))
            {
                $suffix = $this->input->post("suffix");
                $fn = $this->input->post("fn");
                $mn = $this->input->post("mn");
                $ln = $this->input->post("ln");


                $newdata = array('suffix'=>$suffix,
                                'fn'=>$fn,
                                'mn'=>$mn,
                                'ln'=>$ln,

                                 );
                //this code is for the file upload
                           $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads';
                           $config['allowed_types'] = '*';

                           $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                           $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                 //end of file upload codes                 

                $this->db->insert('myself', $newdata); 

                redirect(base_url() . "site/complaint");    

            }

        }
```

view (cmain.php)

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>site/m1" name="details" id="details" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table class='table' width="100%">
            <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
                <b><font color="#3B608C">Personal Information</font></b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Suffix  (e.g. Jr., III)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="suffix" id="suffix" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                First Name*
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="fn" id="fn" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Middle Name*
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="mn" id="mn" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Last Name*
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="ln" id="ln" value="">
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>

            <table>
        <tr>
        <td width="50%">
        Please attach documents pertinent to these complaints. <br>
        (Attach a zip file if more than one document)<br>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
        <input name = "userfile" type="file" class="input-xlarge" id = "userfile" />
        </td></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" class="pull-right" id="submit" name="m1"/>
</form>
```

the form posts properly in the database like the suffix,fn,ln and mn
however the file upload isnt working

i tried my best to follow what the codeigniter docs samples and only got the lines i think i needed

am i doing something wrong?

thanks

Comment: try using the validation class. and then set the image upload as a custom callback.

Answer (score 6):

finally got it working

i used this for the file upload part

```
                //start of file upload code
                $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->do_upload();
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                //end of file upload code
```

and changed the

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>site/m1" name="details" id="details" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

into

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('site/c_upload');?>
```

Comment: what is c_upload? i don't see a function named c_upload in the controller

Answer (score 1):

I think you must have to set file upload preference

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '768';
```

Form Helper

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
```

[For further detail have a look at my blog post](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/codeigniter-upload-file-image/)

Answer (score 0):

- Did you set writing permissions for 'uploads' folder?  (example: php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)
- Always do test driven development. I got below code block from [this url](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

  ```
  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
  {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

      $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In your Codeigniter -> Config -> AutoLoad.php; add the following:

```
  public $helpers = ['form', 'url'];
```